# Is there a more concise way to create a std::wstring from an API that returns a wchar_t**?

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to generate a `std::wstring` from the Win32 function [`GetThreadDescription()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreaddescription) function.

Currently, I am doing it like this:

```cpp
wchar_t thread_desc[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t* p = &thread_desc[0];
check_hr(GetThreadDescription(GetCurrentThread(), &p));
std::wstring wthread = std::wstring(p);
```

However this seems really awkward and I wonder if there's a more concise way?

Comment: You don't need `thread_desc`, just initialize `p` to NULL. `GetThreadDescription` doesn't write to the user-provided buffer, it allocates its own buffer with `LocalAlloc`. Your code leaks it, by the way. Anyway, if you need to do this often, just write your own wrapper that returns `std::wstring`, so you only need to write this awkward sequence once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetThreadDescription()` takes a `wchar_t**` parameter because it outputs a new `wchar_t*`. IOW, it allocates its own buffer for the string data and assigns that buffer to the `wchar_t*` that you have to provide.  As such, your `thread_desc[]` array is useless and will just waste memory, so get rid of it. `GetThreadDescription()` will re-assign your `p` to point at the memory it allocates, which you must free with `LocalFree()` when you are done using it, eg.

```cpp
wchar_t* p = NULL;
check_hr(GetThreadDescription(GetCurrentThread(), &p));
std::wstring wthread(p);
LocalFree(p);
```

So, to answer your question - because `GetThreadDescription()` allocates its own memory, there is no more concise way to convert that data into a `std::wstring`, no.  The only thing you can possibly do is wrap the output `wchar_t*` into an RAII object to ensure `LocalFree()` gets called even if the `std::wstring` constructor throws an exception.

Answer (score -5):

You don't have to create a buffer variable like `wchar_t thread_desc[MAX_PATH]`

Just pass pointer an initialized with nullptr, this method allocates memory with it's internal methods, you need to free this buffer later by calling LocalFree().:

And no, there is no way to do it more concise. Yes, you can create a `std::wstring str`, call `str.resize(MAX_PATH)` and then pass a `&str[0]` but i highly not recommending to do such things, std::string is not intended for direct writing zero-terminated strings into it's buffer. `length() of this string will equal MAX_PATH and it will cause a lot of problems. So initializing a std::wstring from a buffer is the best way to wrap WinAPI results into C++ strings.

Comment: "std::string is not intended for direct writing zero-terminated strings into it's buffer" Disagree. This usage is very much supported.

Comment: *"std::string is not intended for direct writing zero-terminated strings into it's buffer"* - So, in your opinion, why does [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) return a pointer to non-`const` starting with C++17? The purpose **is** specifically to support that use case. Obviously, you'll want to account for the NUL terminator prior to setting the `std::string`'s size, but there's no reason not to use a `std::string` when interfacing with a C API.

Comment: @Georgiv "*Yes, you can create a `std::wstring` str, call `str.resize(MAX_PATH)` and then pass a `&str[0]` but i highly not recommending to do such things*" - that approach, while perfectly legal with many C APIs, would not work with `GetThreadDescription()`, so I don't know why you even brought it up in the first place.